# How concatination can be performed between two columns froms different worksheets in vba excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to contactinate data of two columns from two different worksheets using vba macro.
Ex- in an excel sheet there are two tabs/worksheets sheet1 and sheet2. sheet1 is having column firstname & middlename, sheet2 is having column last name. I want to concat all first,middle & last name .

i am able to concat column which are present in same worksheet but not the column from different worksheets. Kindly suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: In which columns is the data and where do you want to put the result?

Comment: in sheet1 column A is having firstname ,column B is having middle name & in sheet2 column A is having lastname. Now i want to concatenate first,middle&last name using vba macro and want to paste the result in column B of sheet 2.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the CONCATENATE function? Open both workbooks and in the destination cell write the CONCATENATE function with the directions.

```
=CONCATENATE(Cell from Workbook 1," ",Cell from Workbook 2)
```

You didn't mention the details of your use case. But if you want something programatic, the code below shows how you can reference different workbooks and worksheets. You can a for loop and modify it for your use case.

```
Sub conc()

Dim destination_Wb as Workbook, wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim destination_Ws as Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Set destination_Wb = Workbooks(“Destination Workbook.xlsm”)
...
...

Set destination_Ws = destination_Wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
...
...

destination_Ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = ws1.Cells(1, 1).Value + " " + ws2.Cells(1, 1).Value

End sub
```

Comment: Though it can be aceived by aplying simple concatenate function in excel but i want to automate something using vba for a large set of data which include this kind of behavior.

Answer (score 0):

As you wanted a VBA solution, I've put something together for you. It checks if the number of rows in columns A in the two sheets are the same, loads the data from columns A/B in the first sheet and column A in the second sheet into an array, and then loops these arrays, concatenating then with spaces between using `Trim` to cater for missing values and writing this to the column B of the second sheet:

```
Sub sConcatenate()
    Dim wsFName As Worksheet
    Dim wsLName As Worksheet
    Dim wsOutput As Worksheet
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim lngLoop1 As Long
    Dim aFName() As Variant
    Dim aMName() As Variant
    Dim aLName() As Variant
    Set wsFName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FName")
    Set wsLName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("LName")
    Set wsOutput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("LName")
    lngLastRow = wsFName.Cells(wsFName.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If lngLastRow = wsOutput.Cells(wsOutput.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row Then
        aFName = wsFName.Range("A1:A" & lngLastRow).Value
        aMName = wsFName.Range("B1:B" & lngLastRow).Value
        aLName = wsLName.Range("A1:A" & lngLastRow).Value
        For lngLoop1 = LBound(aFName, 1) To UBound(aFName, 1)
            wsOutput.Cells(lngLoop1, 2) = Trim(Trim(aFName(lngLoop1, 1) & " " & aMName(lngLoop1, 1)) & " " & aLName(lngLoop1, 1))
        Next lngLoop1
    End If
    Set wsFName = Nothing
    Set wsLName = Nothing
    Set wsOutput = Nothing
End Sub
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

### Concatenate Columns

Adjust the values in the constants section.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ConcatNames()
    Const Source As String = "Sheet1"
    Const Target As String = "Sheet2"
    Const NameColumn As Long = 1
    Const MiddleNameColumn As Long = 2
    Const LastNameColumn As Long = 1
    Const FullNameColumn As Long = 2
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim vName, vMiddle, vLast, vFull
    Dim RowsCount As Long, i As Long
    Dim CurrString As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Source)
        Set rng = .Columns(NameColumn).Find(What:="*", _
          LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(FirstRow, NameColumn), rng)
        vName = rng
        RowsCount = rng.Rows.Count
        Set rng = .Cells(FirstRow, MiddleNameColumn).Resize(RowsCount)
        vMiddle = rng
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Target)
        Set rng = .Cells(FirstRow, LastNameColumn).Resize(RowsCount)
        vLast = rng
    End With

    ReDim vFull(1 To RowsCount, 1 To 1)
    For i = 1 To RowsCount
        GoSub BuildString
    Next i

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Target)
        Set rng = .Cells(FirstRow, FullNameColumn).Resize(RowsCount)
        rng = vFull
    End With

Exit Sub

BuildString:
    If vName(i, 1) = "" Then Return
    CurrString = vName(i, 1)
    If vMiddle(i, 1) <> "" Then CurrString = CurrString & " " & vMiddle(i, 1)
    If vLast(i, 1) <> "" Then CurrString = CurrString & " " & vLast(i, 1)
    vFull(i, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Trim(CurrString)
Return

End Sub
```